# Changing a watsapp group name

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I changed a watsapp group name and then back again to the original name. will everyone get notified of the changed name I didnt use?
Its just a work group and Im mortified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Every member of the group will be notified when you change(s):

• Group Name

• Group Description

• Group Icon